# PHP single select * COMPLICATED TO WORD

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently creating a voting module for my website, and i have to check if the user voted already, it would just select * from the vote logs, my script inserts a new record for each vote, so say you vote on site 1 its a different record, then say if you voted for site 2.

The columns are site, and the username. I wan't to be able to check if they voted on all sites based on their username in one php mysql query SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME

And then sort through the information that way, but i can't wrap my head around it....

Any help's appreciated as always!

Comment: How do you know what "all sites" are? Do you have another table that lists them all? Can you show the table definitions of both tables?

Comment: If you know the total count of the sites, simply do something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes_log WHERE username = <your_user_name>` and see if it's equal to the total count of all sites.

Comment: If username is your unique key field then it's impossible to insert a second username vote.

Comment: Sure hold on

vote_log

id
usn
site (integer between 0 and 4)
timestamp
used (checks if its a valid vote that hasn't been redeemed)

Comment: Pateman, i think i'm gonna try your solution! I never thought of this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would set it up:

Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE users(    
    userid    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX(username)
);
```

Sites table:

```
CREATE TABLE sites(    
    siteid    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sitename  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX(sitename)
);
```

Votes table:

```
CREATE TABLE votes(    
    timestamp timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    userid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    siteid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX(userid,siteid)
);
```

When a user casts a vote:

```
INSERT INTO votes(userid,siteid) VALUES ("$userid","$siteid")
```

To see what sites a user has voted on:

```
SELECT sites.sitename FROM sites
INNER JOIN votes ON sites.siteid=votes.voteid
WHERE votes.userid="$userid"
```

To see what sites a user has NOT voted on (if no rows are returned, then the user has voted on every site):

```
SELECT sitename FROM sites
WHERE siteid NOT IN (
    SELECT siteid FROM votes WHERE userid="$userid"
)
```

I like this solution, because then you can display which sites the user has not voted on.

**A couple final notes**:  (1) Never, EVER use "SELECT * FROM table" in a production setting; this is terrible performance.  Always select the only the rows you need.  And (2) be sure to quote the user input on your queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the extra tables! never thought of doing it like that. I love this site....